# I am not able to build the apk file of the project, whenever I try to build I get thi error. dexBuilderDebug FAILED

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

[I am getting this error while trying to build the APK file of the project.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObM8G.png)

This is my Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])





    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'


    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'

    //okhttp logging interceptor
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.12.0'

    //Retrofit Library
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    implementation 'io.github.shashank02051997:FancyToast:2.0.2'


    //External Libraries-------------------

    implementation 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ceryle:RadioRealButton:v1.3'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
}
```

I tried all the solutions in Stack Over Flow but not able to find the reason for this, Can Someone please explain me that why I am getting this error and what is the solution for this?

Comment: Does have a public repository?

Answer (score 0):

By seeing the attached screenshots

I think this could be because by default (**gradle.properties**) `android.enableR8.fullMode=true` make it `android.enableR8.fullMode=false` and trying it will create the APK